Create Siri UserActivities for swiftUI vpn app to connect/disconnect vpn
i im currently developing vpn app and i want to add siri shortcuts for users so that for example when user enters youtube - my vpn appExtension disconnects vpn or connects it depending on what shortcut user selected.
I tried to add activities to appDelegate but it didnt work. I also added my activityTypes to infoPlist.
this is code sample:
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(checkIfScheduleNeeded),
                                               name: .userStartedSubscriptionAutoUpdates,
                                               object: nil)
        
        setupBackgroundFetch()
        askForInternetConnectionAtFirstLaunch()
        PushNotificationManager.shared.requestNotificationAuthorization()
        
        donateConnectVPNShortcut()
        donateDisconnectVPNShortcut()
        
        return true
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
                     continue userActivity: NSUserActivity,
                     restorationHandler: @escaping ([any UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
        if userActivity.activityType == Constants.connectVPNSiriActivityType {
            guard let status = packetTunnelManager.status,
                  status == .disconnected else { return true }
            Task {
                do {
                    try await packetTunnelManager.start()
                } catch let error {
                    print("Couldnt connect vpn though Siri shortcuts error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
        } else if userActivity.activityType == Constants.disconnectVPNSiriActivityType {
            guard let status = packetTunnelManager.status,
                  status == .connected else { return true }
            packetTunnelManager.stop()
        }
        
        return true
    }
    
    // MARK: - Private methods
    private func donateConnectVPNShortcut() {
        let siriShortcutConnectVPNTitle = NSLocalizedString("siriShortcutConnectVPNTitle", comment: "Title for Connect VPN Shortcut")
        
        let activity = NSUserActivity(activityType: Constants.connectVPNSiriActivityType)
        activity.title = siriShortcutConnectVPNTitle
        activity.suggestedInvocationPhrase = siriShortcutConnectVPNTitle
        activity.isEligibleForSearch = true
        activity.isEligibleForPrediction = true
        activity.persistentIdentifier = NSUserActivityPersistentIdentifier(Constants.connectVPNSiriActivityType)
        
        activity.becomeCurrent()
    }

    private func donateDisconnectVPNShortcut() {
        let siriShortcutDisconnectVPNTitle = NSLocalizedString("siriShortcutDisconnectVPNTitle", comment: "Title for disconnect VPN Shortcut")
        
        let activity = NSUserActivity(activityType: Constants.disconnectVPNSiriActivityType)
        activity.title = siriShortcutDisconnectVPNTitle
        activity.suggestedInvocationPhrase = siriShortcutDisconnectVPNTitle
        activity.isEligibleForSearch = true
        activity.isEligibleForPrediction = true
        activity.persistentIdentifier = NSUserActivityPersistentIdentifier(Constants.disconnectVPNSiriActivityType)
        
        activity.becomeCurrent()
    }

Currently cant find a good way to add siri shortcuts for ios 15 (my target ios version)
Can provide more context if needed.
TY
